# sys_write in assembly [msg] or msg?

Tags: linux, assembly, operating-system

Here is the sample example from [this link](http://asm.sourceforge.net/intro/hello.html):

```
section     .text
global      _start                              ;must be declared for 
_start:                                         ;tell linker entry point

mov     edx,len                             ;message length
mov     ecx,msg                             ;message to write
mov     ebx,1                               ;file descriptor (stdout)
mov     eax,4                               ;system call number (sys_write)
int     0x80                                ;call kernel

mov     eax,1                               ;system call number (sys_exit)
int     0x80                                ;call kernel

section     .data

msg     db  'Hello, world!',0xa                 ;our dear string
len     equ $ - msg                             ;length of our dear string
```

As you can see we have used msg (mov ecx,msg).

However as far as I know that msg will point to the address of "Hello, world".

If we want to get the "Hello, world" itself, **shouldn't we use [msg]???**

Comment: `sys_write` expects an address so that's fine. `[msg]` would just load the first 4 characters of the string which makes no sense.

Comment: thanks for quick response :) may I ask why [msg] loads the first 4 characters ?

Comment: See also [man 2 write](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html) and notice the `void*`.

Comment: actually I have tried mov ecx, [msg] and it has nothing printed to the screen

Comment: @monstereo `ecx` is 32 bit register, and `db 'Hello ...'` encodes string into machine code (later content of memory when running) by ASCII encoding, ASCII encoding => 1 byte = 1 char. 32 bits = 4 bytes. So loading 32 bits from memory containing ASCII string = loading 4 chars.

Comment: @Ped7g many thanks, I understood now...

Comment: @monstereo try it in debugger, and see if you can recognize the chars themselves in the register (they are reasonably visible in hexadecimal, if you have suspicion (especially digits are easy to spot, as '0' = 0x30, '1' = 0x31, etc...). Hexa because one hexadecimal digit is exactly 4 bits "wide" (4 bits = 16 combinations and there are 16 digits in hexadecimal) .. i.e. hexadecimal formatting allows to read separate bits after some practice, and each pair of hexa digits = one byte.

Comment: `mov ecx, [msg]` does load the 4 characters into `ecx` but since `write` expects a pointer those will not be printed.